# Python scraping from Yahoo finance error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to scrape data from income statements on *Yahoo Finance* using Python.

I would like to extract **Net Income** that´s in enclosed in:

[image: Yahoo_Finance_Screen]

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&annual'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
pattern = re.compile('Net Income')

title = soup.find('strong', text=pattern)
row = title.parent.parent 
cells = row.find_all('td')[1:] #exclude the <td> with 'Net Income'

values = [ c.text.strip() for c in cells ]
```

But I´m getting this error:

[image: error_console]

Do you know what can be causing the issue?

Comment: Lorenzo your text is not surrounded by strong tag! it's span.

Comment: Hi @Ehsan sure, thanks for point it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the Net Income values by searching for the 'div' tag instead. This should do the trick:

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=AAPL&annual'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find('div', string=re.compile('Net Income'))
row = title.parent.parent 
values = [i.text for i in row]
print(values[1:])
```

Result:

`['57,215,000', '55,256,000', '59,531,000', '48,351,000', '45,687,000']`